# Is there a similar method in java as pbinom in R?

Tags: java, r

Guys I want to find the confidence intervals in java. I checked out the Binomial Distribution class in Apache Commons, but not sure if what I am looking for is in there.

Have another question, I have the following equation

```
pbinom (9,10,x)=0.8
```

How do I solve it using `uniroot` in R? I have absolutely no knowledge of R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to solve this equation in R? To get help with a particular function in R run `?pbinom`. As you will see `pbinom` is the binomial cdf. The first 2 arguments are a particular quantile and number of trials. So solving 
pbinom(9,10,x)=0.8 is essentially asking at value of `prob` (Probability of Success) is  the chance that there is 9 successes or fewer equal to 0.8. Solving this exactly requires some nasty algebra but, you can graph it and get an idea of the answer using

```
func=function(x)pbinom(9,10,x)
dum=seq(0,1, length=10^4)
plot(dum, func(dum), type='l')
abline(h=0.8, lty=2)
```

[image]

As you might suspect this occurs around a very high probability (about 0.851) because at low probabilities we would almost always have 9 successes or fewer.

Comment: Is there a way to this binomial cdf in java? Although I am doing it but connectivity with R would be a little slower than doing it in java itself. Thanks.

Comment: One more question, instead of plotting the graph is there a way to get the probability value? @justin1.618

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. Idk of anyway to implement the binomial cdf in Java. As for the probability value, like I said I don't think it can be solved exactly but it's close to 0.851.

Comment: I have managed to create one already in java, and I was also able to get the exact probability value too in R, thanks for help.